# Delete overlapping points between two shapefiles QGIS

Tags: qgis, point

I have a point shapefile of all human settlements in South Africa (ranging from tiny hamlets to major cities). In another shapefile, I have point features as well, representing settlements located inside an urban area.

I'd like to join the cities falling inside the urban extent to the shapefile of all settlements. However, if I do so I will get repeated features (cities in the urban extent also exist in the human settlement shapefile).
Is there a way to avoid having this happen? 
The first picture represents all the human settlements, and the second only the settlements inside an urban extent.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can `remove duplicate geometries` after joining both files.

Comment: You could do a Vector -> Research Tools -> Select By Location as well. Just set the 'Where the features (geometric predicate)' to equal. Then just delete the selected points before doing the join

Comment: @Tim56 did you solve your problem? If you did, could you add as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing duplicate geometries after joining both files. This worked perfectly.